# Unusual print() behaviour while running python script in background

Tags: python

I have a simple python script which goes for 5 seconds sleep. I am running the script in background. I have a small print statement before I call sleep function. But I am unable to get the prompt back unless I mannually hit enter. When I comment the print statemet, I get the prompt back.
The script does go into background in both the cases though.

```py
import time
print("going to sleep")
time.sleep(5)
```

When I run the script with print statement in it, I don't get the prompt back.

```
USER-M-L0DD:Downloads user$python3 sleep.py &
[1] 10993
USER-M-L0DD:Downloads user$ going to sleep
```

I have to manually press enter here to get my prompt back.

When I run it without print statement, I get the prompt back.

```
USER-M-L0DD:Downloads user$ python3 sleep.py &
[1] 11588
USER-M-L0DD:Downloads user$
```

Comment: Could you show the actual output? I assume that `going to sleep` must appear somewhere.

Comment: @Nikhil Chhabria in my case code is working ok

Comment: The script as-is doesn't really do anything. You may as well get rid of `sleep` altogether. So that, to me, suggests something else that you haven't shown

Comment: You *do* get the prompt back, it's only that the process writes to stdout after that.

Comment: It seems more like a Unix command line issue than a Python printing issue to me. what happens if you remove that `&` at the end?

Comment: @mkrieger1 you are right. The prompt is coming back but the print output is printed on that which created the confusion all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected. You DO get the prompt back. It's staring you in the face:

```
USER-M-L0DD:Downloads user$python3 sleep.py &
[1] 10993
USER-M-L0DD:Downloads user$ going to sleep
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ < Look: there is your prompt
```

what happens is that when the python script runs, it also sends its output to the console, and it is printed *after* the prompt. But the shell is still sitting there waiting for your input.

Without the print statement, nothing is output to the console so you don't see any additional output after the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

> When I run the script with print statement in it, I don't get the
>   prompt back.

```
USER-M-L0DD:Downloads user$ python3 sleep.py &
[1] 10993
USER-M-L0DD:Downloads user$ going to sleep
                      ^^^^^
                      there is your prompt
```

> I have to manually press enter here to get my prompt back.

Then I guess it looks like this:

```
USER-M-L0DD:Downloads user$ python3 sleep.py &
[1] 10993
USER-M-L0DD:Downloads user$ going to sleep
USER-M-L0DD:Downloads user$
```

You actually get *another* prompt.